# ¿Cómo acceder a una ruta con prefijo desde AngularJS (Angular 1) ?, en Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5, laravel

Tengo un inconveniente, no sé cómo acceder a una ruta en Laravel que cuenta con un prefijo, el cuál, es un parámetro llamado {username}.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/{username}/pos-settings', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'editpage']], function ($username){

Route::resource('api/itemkittemp', 'ItemKitController');
Route::get('api/item-kit-temp', 'ItemKitController@itemKitApi');
Route::get('api/item-kits', 'ItemKitController@itemKits');
Route::post('store-item-kits', 'ItemKitController@storeItemKits');

});
```

En ItemKitController.php

```
class ItemKitController extends Controller{

    public function __construct(){

        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
    */

    public function index($username){

       $timeline = Timeline::where('username', $username)->with('page')->first();

       $itemkits = Item::where('type', 2)->get();

       $theme = Theme::uses(Setting::get('current_theme', 'default'))->layout('default');

       return $theme->scope('pos/itemkit/index', compact('timeline', 'itemkits' ))->render();
    }

    /**
    * Show the form for creating a new resource.
    *
    * @return Response
    */

    public function create($username){

       $timeline = Timeline::where('username', $username)->with('page')->first();

       $theme = Theme::uses(Setting::get('current_theme', 'default'))->layout('default');

       return $theme->scope('pos/itemkit/create', compact('timeline' ))->render();
    }

    /**
    * Store a newly created resource in storage.
    *
    * @return Response
    */

   public function store(){

      $ItemKitItemTemps = new ItemKitItemTemp;
      $ItemKitItemTemps->item_id = Input::get('item_id');
      $ItemKitItemTemps->quantity = 1;
      $ItemKitItemTemps->cost_price = Input::get('cost_price');
      $ItemKitItemTemps->selling_price = Input::get('selling_price');
      $ItemKitItemTemps->save();

      return $ItemKitItemTemps;
   }

   /**
   * Display the specified resource.
   *
   * @param  int  $id
   * @return Response
   */

   public function show($id){

      //
   }

   /**
   * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
   *
   * @param  int  $id
   * @return Response
   */

   public function edit($id){

      //
   }

   /**
   * Update the specified resource in storage.
   *
   * @param  int  $id
   * @return Response
   */

   public function update($id){

      $ItemKitItemTemps = ItemKitItemTemp::find($id);
      $ItemKitItemTemps->quantity = Input::get('quantity');
      $ItemKitItemTemps->save();

      return $ItemKitItemTemps;
   }

   /**
   * Remove the specified resource from storage.
   *
   * @param  int  $id
   * @return Response
   */

   public function destroy($id){

      ItemKitItemTemp::destroy($id);
   }

   public function itemKitApi(){

      return Response::json(ItemKitItemTemp::with('item')->get());
   }

   public function itemKits(){

      return Response::json(Item::where('type', 1)->get());
   }

   public function storeItemKits(ItemKitRequest $request){

      $itemkits = new Item;
      $itemkits->item_name = Input::get('item_kit_name');
      $itemkits->cost_price = Input::get('cost_price');
      $itemkits->selling_price = Input::get('selling_price');
      $itemkits->description = Input::get('description');
      $itemkits->type = 2;
      $itemkits->save();

      // process receiving items

      $item_kit_items = ItemKitItemTemp::all();
      foreach ($item_kit_items as $value) {
         $item_kit_items_data = new ItemKitItem;
         $item_kit_items_data->item_kit_id = $itemkits->id;
         $item_kit_items_data->item_id = $value->item_id;
         $item_kit_items_data->quantity = $value->quantity;
         $item_kit_items_data->save();
      }

       //delete all data on ReceivingTemp model

       ItemKitItemTemp::truncate();
       Session::flash('message', 'You have successfully added Item Kits');
       return Redirect::to('item-kits/create');
    }
}
```

En item.kits.js

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('tutapos', [ ]);

    app.controller("SearchItemCtrl", [ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.items = [ ];
        $http.get('../api/item-kits').success(function(data) {
            $scope.items = data;
        });

    $scope.itemkittemp = [ ];
    $scope.newitemkittemp = { };
    $http.get('../../api/item-kit-temp').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.itemkittemp = data;
    });

    $scope.addItemKitTemp = function(item){
        $http.post('../../api/itemkittemp', {item_id: item.id, cost_price: item.cost_price, selling_price: item.selling_price }).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            $scope.itemkittemp.push(data);
            $http.get('../../api/item-kit-temp').success(function(data) {
            $scope.itemkittemp = data;
            });
        });
    }

    $scope.updateItemKitTemp = function(newitemkittemp){

        $http.put('../../api/itemkittemp/' + newitemkittemp.id, { quantity: newitemkittemp.quantity }).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        });
    }

    $scope.removeItemKitTemp = function(id) {
        $http.delete('../../api/itemkittemp/' + id).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $http.get('../../api/item-kit-temp').success(function(data) {
            $scope.itemkittemp = data;
            });
        });
    }     

    $scope.sumCost = function(list){
        var total=0;
        angular.forEach(list , function(newitemkittemp){
            total+= parseFloat(newitemkittemp.item.cost_price * newitemkittemp.quantity);
        });

        return total;
    }

    $scope.sumSell = function(list) {
        var total=0;
        angular.forEach(list , function(newitemkittemp){
            total+= parseFloat(newitemkittemp.item.selling_price * newitemkittemp.quantity);
        });

    return total;
}

}]);
})();
```

Y mi vista create.blade.php

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox" aria-hidden="true"></span> {{trans('itemkit.new_item_kit')}}</div>

    <div class="panel-body">

        @if (Session::has('message'))
            <div class="alert alert-info">{{ Session::get('message') }}</div>
        @endif
        {!! Html::ul($errors->all()) !!}

        <div class="row" ng-controller="SearchItemCtrl">

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label>{{trans('itemkit.search_item')}} <input ng-model="searchKeyword" class="form-control"></label>

                <table class="table table-hover">
                <tr ng-repeat="item in items  | filter: searchKeyword | limitTo:10">

                <td>@{{item.item_name}}</td><td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" type="button" ng-click="addItemKitTemp(item)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></td>

                </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-9">

                <div class="row">

                    {!! Form::open(array('url' => 'store-item-kits', 'class' => 'form-horizontal')) !!}
                        <div class="col-md-6">


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="item_kit_name" class="col-sm-4 control-label">{{trans('itemkit.item_kit_name')}}</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="item_kit_name" id="item_kit_name"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="description" class="col-sm-4 control-label">{{trans('itemkit.description')}}</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" id="description"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>

                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr><th>{{trans('itemkit.item_id')}}</th><th>{{trans('itemkit.item_name')}}</th><th>{{trans('itemkit.quantity')}}</th><th>&nbsp;</th></tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="newitemkittemp in itemkittemp">
                    <td>@{{newitemkittemp.item_id}}</td><td>@{{newitemkittemp.item.item_name}}</td><td><input type="text" style="text-align:center" autocomplete="off" name="quantity" ng-change="updateItemKitTemp(newitemkittemp)" ng-model="newitemkittemp.quantity" size="2"></td><td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" type="button" ng-click="removeItemKitTemp(newitemkittemp.id)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <div class="row">    
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="cost_price" class="col-sm-4 control-label">{{trans('itemkit.cost_price')}}</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <div class="input-group">

                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cost_price_ori" id="cost_price_ori" ng-model="sumCost(itemkittemp)" readonly/>
                                        <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cost_price" id="cost_price" ng-model="cp"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div>&nbsp;</div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="selling_price" class="col-sm-4 control-label">{{trans('itemkit.selling_price')}}</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <div class="input-group">

                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="selling_price_ori" id="selling_price_ori" ng-model="sumSell(itemkittemp)" readonly/>
                                <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="selling_price" id="selling_price" ng-model="sp"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="supplier_id" class="col-sm-5 control-label">{{trans('itemkit.profit')}}</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-7">
                                    <p class="form-control-static"><b>@{{sp - cp}}</b></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div>&nbsp;</div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-block">{{trans('itemkit.submit')}}</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                    {!! Form::close() !!}



            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]